# How to search value and append from a Json Format from a List of Dictionary of List of Dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, api, dictionary

I retrieved this data from an API for vaccine information and I am trying to build an automated telegram bot. But the problem is that I cannot extract data from the following response from API.
The response is:-

```
{
    "centers": [{
        "center_id":
        7964,
        "name":
        "MCW Vishwakarma Park PHC",
        "address":
        "HEALTH CENTRE VISHWAKARMA PARK, NEAR MCD PRIMARY SCHOOL, KRISHAN KUNJ",
        "state_name":
        "Delhi",
        "district_name":
        "East Delhi",
        "block_name":
        "Not Applicable",
        "pincode":
        110092,
        "lat":
        28,
        "long":
        77,
        "from":
        "09:00:00",
        "to":
        "17:00:00",
        "fee_type":
        "Free",
        "sessions": [{
            "session_id":
            "2f812c88-114e-4fea-8a86-3ddc44c9145a",
            "date":
            "20-05-2021",
            "available_capacity":
            0,
            "min_age_limit":
            45,
            "vaccine":
            "COVAXIN",
            "slots": [
                "09:00AM-11:00AM", "11:00AM-01:00PM", "01:00PM-03:00PM",
                "03:00PM-05:00PM"
            ],
            "available_capacity_dose1":
            10,
            "available_capacity_dose2":
            0
        }, {
            "session_id":
            "1c0bc496-7264-4518-b82e-8786a11a398a",
            "date":
            "22-05-2021",
            "available_capacity":
            0,
            "min_age_limit":
            45,
            "vaccine":
            "COVAXIN",
            "slots": [
                "09:00AM-11:00AM", "11:00AM-01:00PM", "01:00PM-03:00PM",
                "03:00PM-05:00PM"
            ],
            "available_capacity_dose1":
            0,
            "available_capacity_dose2":
            20
        }, {
            "session_id":
            "e388e00b-68a1-49df-ac63-bc63a8e4726e",
            "date":
            "24-05-2021",
            "available_capacity":
            0,
            "min_age_limit":
            45,
            "vaccine":
            "COVAXIN",
            "slots": [
                "09:00AM-11:00AM", "11:00AM-01:00PM", "01:00PM-03:00PM",
                "03:00PM-05:00PM"
            ],
            "available_capacity_dose1":
            0,
            "available_capacity_dose2":
            0
        }, {
            "session_id":
            "1cd3e0c8-86a6-4786-8426-c95d0da46ab4",
            "date":
            "25-05-2021",
            "available_capacity":
            0,
            "min_age_limit":
            45,
            "vaccine":
            "COVAXIN",
            "slots": [
                "09:00AM-11:00AM", "11:00AM-01:00PM", "01:00PM-03:00PM",
                "03:00PM-05:00PM"
            ],
            "available_capacity_dose1":
            21,
            "available_capacity_dose2":
            0
        }]
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I extract data with `available_capacity_dose1 > 0 or available_capacity_dose2 > 0` and sort it with key as date.

I tried doing it with `filter()` but I got the entire list as output rather than having individual sessions with different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get sessions where one of the doses is greater than zero, you can do something like the following

```py
out = []
for center in data['centers']:
    for session in center['sessions']:
        if session['available_capacity_dose1'] > 0 or session['available_capacity_dose2'] > 0:
            out.append(session)

print(out)
```

NB: This leaves out any information about the center, which you might want to keep if you have multiple centers. A very crude way of adding that information would be replacing `out.append(session)` with the following in the `if` statement

```py
tmp = dict(session)
tmp['center_id'] = center['center_id']
out.append(tmp)
```

Finally, to sort the data, you could do the following

```py
s_out = sorted(out, key=lambda x: x['date'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I would update this implementation in my code. I would be grateful if you could help me with this query:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645308/how-to-cache-an-api-for-vaccine-availability-telegram-bot